# Separation of Overlapping and Touching Lines

Tags: matlab, lines, overlapping, image-segmentation, handwriting-recognition

Can anyone suggest an approach or method for the separation of overlapping and touching lines within handwritten documents?

I can segment text lines. Now i want to separate the connected lines.

Here it is my image:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You try using the watershed over the distance function of the connected component set to separate them like [here](http://www.mathworks.fr/company/newsletters/articles/the-watershed-transform-strategies-for-image-segmentation.html) and [here](https://opencv-code.com/tutorials/count-and-segment-overlapping-objects-with-watershed-and-distance-transform/). Though its possible it could oversegment the result based on the shapes.

Comment: thank you for your response. I already try this method here some results obtained http://oi39.tinypic.com/adkprk.jpg and http://oi39.tinypic.com/29e6p86.jpg ... I not only separates the overlapping lines but also separate lines not overlap. I think this method is inappropriate for the shapes lines and I don't see how i could oversegment the result based on the shapes.